# Retrieve images from database using linq mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 tables ProductDetails and Images, I am saving thumbnail image into ProductsDetail table and all other related images into Images table. Saving is fine, but I am struggling with Image retrival.
I want to retrieve the thumbnail image of the product from image table not from the productDetail table.
I need help regarding this logic and please help with some code examples. Also please please let me know if the logic is correct or wrong? please see the classes below

```
    public class ProductDetail
    {
        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string pro_name { get; set; }              
        public string pro_model { get; set; }
        public string pro_Dimensions { get; set; }            
        public string pro_imageTitle { get; set; }   // (thumbnail image)
        public string pro_image { get; set; }               
        public string pro_desc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> pro_price { get; set; }         
        public int pro_UnitsInStock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> pro_oldprice { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<Images> tbl_Images { get; set; }

    }



 public class Images
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently, I have tried some linq code, but it is returning duplicate products,I just want to show 1 thumbnail for each product.

```
   IEnumerable<ProductList> List =
                     (from  prod in this.storeDB.tbl_Product  
                     join img in this.storeDB.tbl_Images on prod.pro_id 
                     equals img.pro_id
        select new ProductList
                     {
                         pro_id = prod.pro_id,
                         pro_name = prod.pro_name,
                         pro_model = prod.pro_model,
                         pro_Dimensions = prod.pro_dimensions,
                         pro_UnitsInStock = (int)prod.pro_UnitsInStock,
                         pro_oldprice = prod.pro_oldprice,
                         pro_price = (double)prod.pro_price,
                         pro_isFeatured = prod.pro_isFeatured,
                         pro_isOnSale = prod.pro_isOnSale,
                         pro_desc = prod.pro_desc,
                         ImageID  =img.img_id,
                         ImageTitle = img.ImageTitle                                                      
                     });
```

Comment: Please add some logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably several images in the image table that return duplicate values.

First group the **image** table and then `join` the result with the **product** table.

```
IEnumerable<ProductList> List =
         (from img in this.storeDB.tbl_Images
          group img by img.pro_id into imggr
          join prod in this.storeDB.tbl_Product on imggr.pro_id
          equals prod.pro_id
          select new ProductList
          {
              pro_id = prod.pro_id,
              pro_name = prod.pro_name,
              pro_model = prod.pro_model,
              pro_Dimensions = prod.pro_dimensions,
              pro_UnitsInStock = (int)prod.pro_UnitsInStock,
              pro_oldprice = prod.pro_oldprice,
              pro_price = (double)prod.pro_price,
              pro_isFeatured = prod.pro_isFeatured,
              pro_isOnSale = prod.pro_isOnSale,
              pro_desc = prod.pro_desc,
              ImageID = imggr.FirstOrDefault().img_id,
              ImageTitle = imggr.FirstOrDefault().ImageTitle
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding a flag for thumbnail image in the image table.